# Click on pressing Enter key in a simple login form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple login form which executes a function when the "Login" button is pressed. What I would like to do is give the user the ability to press the Enter key anywhere on the page to trigger the Login button as if it was a click. However, I would like to make it so you don't have to be in a specific textbox/input for it to work. I would like the user to fill out the user/password and then be able to press Enter to login.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
    <form id="login" method="post" name="login">
  <p>Username:</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" id="username" />
  <p>Password:
    <p>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="password" />
      <input type="button" value="Login" id="enter" onclick="compare()" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function compare() {
  let user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  let pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (user === "hello" && pass === "world") {
    console.log("Welcome.");
    alert("Welcome!");
  }
}
```

I've also recently found out about "Unobtrusive JavaScript", so if there's a way to implement that here I would be happy to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen keydown event

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" id="username"  onkeydown="handleEnter(event)"/>


<script>
function handleEnter(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
      compare()
  }
}

function compare() {
  let user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  let pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (user === "hello" && pass === "world") {
    console.log("Welcome.");
    alert("Welcome!");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's kinda close but not exactly what I'm looking for. I want it to work "anywhere" on the page". For example, the user can click outside of the textbox and still be able to press Enter to login.

Comment: then you need to listen document onkeydown like `document.addEventListener('keydown', handleEnter)`

Comment: How would I go about implementing this with multiple functions?

For example, say that first you enter your username, press the Enter key, and a new function is called to show the password field. Then, after entering your password and presing Enter, a different function is called to show a "Welcome" message.

Is this possible to do with if statements inside the handleEnter function?

Comment: You can handle all of these in you compare function